# Can't apt-get from shell script

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts

I don't use linux very often, but I need to for this particular python project. Because of that, I'm trying to make an installer for my program using this shell script:

SETUP.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get install python3-pip -y
apt-get install python3-tk -y
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

after chmodding it to be executable, and running `sudo sh SETUP.sh` I get this output:

```
: notfound: SETUP.sh:
E: Invalid operation update
] is not known. option '
] is not known. option '
SETUP.sh: 6: SETUP.sh: pip3: not found
```

The weirdest part is all those commands work on their own if I just manually put them into the command line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why exactly do you run a `#!/bin/bash` script with `sh` rather than `bash`?

Comment: Because I'm a fool.. but that said, it has the same output with `sudo bash ./SETUP.sh` just without the `: notfound: SETUP.sh` line so the problem is something else

Comment: Is there any problem to run the script by: `sudo ./SETUP.sh` - where `./` is the path to the script, the current directory in this case.

Comment: And you do run this command in the very directory where your script is located, do you?

Comment: @pa4080 the output of `./SETUP.sh` is:


   `bash: ./SETUP.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

and yes, it's being run in the same directory it's saved in

Comment: Hm. Where you write this script? Maybe in Windows?

Comment: There is no `/bin/bash` on your system? What does `sudo apt install bash` output? Please always add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) rather than using comments.

Comment: `^M` is the key here, you've got windows line endings! run `dos2unix SETUP.sh`, then redo `chmod +x SETUP.sh`. (`sudo apt install dos2unix` before using it....)

Comment: @pim The linked question has solutions. I prefer the `sed` solution myself, cause you don't need to install anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it looks like the issue has something to do with me not knowing how to run shellscripts, and me porting the script over from a Windows machine. (Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-my-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory))

After re-writing it in vi, and running it with `sudo ./SETUP.sh` it works

Comment: Zaya, please accept this answer.